# rabbitmqadmin list vhosts show messages but there are no queues

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, rabbitmqctl

rabbitmqadmin list vhosts show messages but there are no queues. Why it is possible?

When I run Celery it still somehow receives messages. How can I see the name of the queue where the messages are stored? What do I miss?

```
dmugtasimov@dmugtasimov-ThinkPad-Edge-E440 ~ $ rabbitmqadmin -u guest -p guest list vhosts
+---------+----------+----------------+-------------------------+----------+----------+---------+
|  name   | messages | messages_ready | messages_unacknowledged | recv_oct | send_oct | tracing |
+---------+----------+----------------+-------------------------+----------+----------+---------+
| myvhost | 1        | 1              | 0                       | 231903   | 229228   | False   |
+---------+----------+----------------+-------------------------+----------+----------+---------+
dmugtasimov@dmugtasimov-ThinkPad-Edge-E440 ~ $ rabbitmqadmin -u guest -p guest list queues
No items
dmugtasimov@dmugtasimov-ThinkPad-Edge-E440 ~ $ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues
Listing queues ...
...done.
dmugtasimov@dmugtasimov-ThinkPad-Edge-E440 ~ $ rabbitmqadmin -u guest -p guest -V myvhost get queue=celery requeue=true count=10
*** Access refused: /api/queues/myvhost/celery/get
```

Please, suggest what extra information is required to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

I met the similar problem. the difference is: my message is "unacknowledged"

e.g.  I found my queue has a message:

```
$ rabbitmqadmin list queues name node messages

+----------------------------+----------------+----------+
|            name            |      node      | messages |
+----------------------------+----------------+----------+
| my_queue_name              | rabbit@xx-2    | 1        |
```

but when I run "get" command to show its content, rabbitmq tells me "there's no item"

so, I query it with this command:

```
$ rabbitmqadmin list queues name node messages messages_ready messages_unacknowledged

+----------------------------+----------------+----------+----------------+-------------------------+
|            name            |      node      | messages | messages_ready | messages_unacknowledged |
+----------------------------+----------------+----------+----------------+-------------------------+
| my_queue_name              | rabbit@xxxxx-2 | 1        | 0              | 1                       |
+----------------------------+----------------+----------+----------------+-------------------------+
```

I don't know why. just restart the rabbitmq server and everything seems goes fine.